# Is it possible to publish component revisions within workflow?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Our current setup is that we have two targets, Staging and Live. Collaborators may update the affected component while it is still within the workflow. A final activity is set to publish the related pages to Live. Is it possible to publish component updates (revisions e.g. 2.2, 2.5) to Staging from within the workflow?

The TOM API documentation for **Page.Publish()** method does not seem to have an input parameter to fullfil such purpose.

EDIT: Additional details to our current setup: The page we're trying to publish has a "custom renderer", so to speak. The page template is setup to pull components from a certain folder recursively and build the HTML accordingly. The method used is **Folder.GetItems(OrganizationalItemItemsFilter)**. It retrieves the list of components together with their data. The page doesn't have component presentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For standard Tridion solutions i.e. using Page+ComponentPresentations+Workflow, this will suffice:**

Setting `activateWorkflow` parameter to `True` in the `Publish()` method will publish the workflow revision. It's the 3rd parameter:

```vb
Public Function Publish( ByVal targets As Variant,
            ByVal activateBlueprinting As Boolean,
            ByVal activateWorkflow As Boolean,
            ByVal rollbackOnFailure As Boolean,
            Optional ByVal publishTime As Date = 0,
            Optional ByVal unpublishTime As Date = 0,
            Optional ByVal deployTime As Date = 0,
            Optional ByVal resolveComponentLinks As Boolean = True,
            Optional ByVal priority As TDSDefines.EnumPublishPriority = Normal,
            Optional ByVal ignoreRenderFailures As Boolean = False,
            Optional ByVal maximumRenderFailures As Long = 0 ) As String
```

Reference: TOM API Documentation: "*activateWorkflow | Indicates whether the item is being (un-/re-)published from the user's work list.*"

---

However, if **customized** renderers are used to build page output, like when using `Folder.GetItems()` to retrieve components in templates, additional calls would be required to actually retrieve the latest revision of components such as the [version-zero `-v0` trick](https://forum.sdltridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7504&TID=mfOdK1ky969mxF-kQ4tcWMvsdBRjsma67MFGiFz9T5UhjpEDkZ907GrIvaYGX77Xyg) by Nuno.

Please note that if you decide to do this, the latest revision will always be published to your targets and it may not exactly be "approved" content.

Comment: I tried to use `activateWorkflow` parameter and it worked for one of our workflows. Thank you.

However, it still didn't publish the revision for another workflow that publishes a page using a "custom renderer". Please refer to my recent update to the question.

Comment: You have to execute the publish as a user who has permission to view the revision in WF. That means doing either as an Admin, or as the user that currently owns the WF item (explicitly as that user, or by impersonation). There's a good chance that your custom renderer doesn't do this. Do you have access to the Tridion Forum? There's an interesting discussion on how best to get the revision at https://forum.sdltridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7504.

Comment: Yeah, I do have access to the forums. I have to try the `-v0` trick and impersonation from the template. You may be right, the `Folder.GetItems` method may only be retrieving the latest version (not revision).

Comment: Jeremy, the `-v0` trick worked as well and we're able to get the latest revision from the template. Thanks for helpin out man! I've edited your answer above to provide the distinction between the `Publish()` and solution for our custom renderer. Feel free to edit if something is not clear. Thanks again!